# Where are IBM certificates stored in Information Server?

Tags: ibm-information-server

I'm currently installing IIS EE on EC2 instances in an AWS environment. A question from left field: does anyone happen to know where the IBM certificates are stored?

Attempt: I usually inspect the certificate when handling the exception in a browser but I wants to know which file(s) to check on the services tier.

Comment: This information is available in the Certificate Services MMC, but that's technically systems administration not programming! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which certificates to which you are referring to. There are certificates on each of the tiers and in WAS. For example,

```
/opt/IBM/InformationServer/ASBNode/conf/iis-client-truststore.p12
/opt/IBM/InformationServer/ASBServer/conf/iis-client-truststore.p12
/opt/IBM/InformationServer/ASBServer/conf/isf-node.keystore
```